# How do I use pg_trgm to be more permissible

Tags: postgresql, pg-trgm

I used pg_trgrm to check string matches and I am pretty happy with the results. But it is not pefrectly the way I want it. I want that searches like "poduto" finds "produtos" (the r was missing). And Also that "sofáa" finds "sofa". I am using posgresql 9.6.

It does find "vermelho" when I type "vermelo" (h is missing). And it does find "sofa" when I type "sof". It seems that only some letters in middle can be left out and I always can miss a final letter. I want to be able to miss any letter in the middle of the word. And also be able to commit "two mistakes" in the case of sofáa and sofá (I used an accent and used one additional "a").

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to lower [`pg_trgm.similarity_threshold`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgtrgm.html#id-1.11.7.41.6) (or `pg_trgm.word_similarity_threshold` if you are using `<%` or `%>`).

Then words with lower similarity will also be found.